# Increment operator not working in while condition

Tags: c++, pointers, operators, post-increment

I've written a while loop to increment a pointer until the content is a null byte or the difference between adjacent elements is greater than 1, and this has worked fine:

```cpp
while (i[1] && *i + 1 == i[1]) i++;
```

Then I tried to rewrite it as:

```cpp
while (i[1] && *(i++) + 1 == *i);
```

But in this way, it got stuck in an infinite loop, as if `i` was not being incremented. Why is this so?

Edit:
I must apologize for being misleading but I discovered now that it does not get stuck inside the while loop I showed you, rather it simply exits that while loop and instead gets stuck in its parent loop, let me just share with you the whole code:

```cpp
      char accepted[strlen(literal)+1];
      strcpy(accepted, literal);
      std::sort(accepted, accepted + strlen(accepted));
      char *i = accepted-1;
      while (*++i){
        uint8_t rmin = *i; 
        //while (i[1] && *i + 1 == i[1]) i++;
        while (i[1] && *(i++) + 1 == *i);
        uint8_t rmax = *i; 
        ranges.push_back(Range{rmin, rmax});
        if (!i[1]) break;//is this necessary?
      }
```

My question is no longer valid.

And yes, "clever" unreadable code is a bad idea.

Comment: Because of undefined behaviour. Being clever usually isn't.

Comment: @molbdnilo I don't see UB here (at least at first sight), but rather `i` not being incremented because if `i[1]` is non zero, then `*(i++)` never gets evaluated, hence the infinite loop. But it's true that "clever" unreadable code is usually a bad idea

Comment: The second expression has undefined behaviour as the compiler may evaluate the terms in any order. In the first expression this is not the case.

Comment: @pqans right, there are two distinct problems here.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I don't get your point. If `i[1]` is nonzero, `*(i++) + 1 == *i` does get evaluated, and that is undefined. Or did I miss something?

Comment: @molbdnilo no, you're right, see me previous comment, but there are two problems, the UB you mentioned and the short circuit evaluation problem I mentioned in my first comment

Comment: @MichaelNastenko he's not talking about the `&&` operator but about the order of evaluation of both expressions left and right of the `==` here: `*i + 1 == i[1]`

Comment: Is `i++ == i` true or false? Answer: It's UB. Because `i++` and `i` can be evaluated in any order.

Comment: I removed the C tag because your code is C++ and not C

Comment: Brian Kernighan: "Debugging is twice as hard as writing the code in the first place. Therefore, if you write the code as cleverly as possible, you are, by definition, not smart enough to debug it."

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems in your code:

```
while (i[1] && *(i++) + 1 == *i);
```

- The `&&` operator uses [short circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), that is if the left part (`i[1]`) is 0, then the right part (`*(i++) + 1 == *i`) is never evaluated. That's the reason why your code loops indefinitely.
- the expression `*(i++) + 1 == *i` yields undefined behaviour because the [order of evaluation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/eval_order) of the sub expressions left and right of the `==` is not specified.

It's usually not advised to write "clever" code. Write readable code and let the compiler take care of optimizations.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but when evaluating &&, wouldn't it be the other way round, that is only if the left part i[1] is 0, the right part is never evaluated? My reasoning is that to evaluate the AND gate you only need to check if one of them is false.

Comment: @Cabbache you're right, I corrected the answer.

Comment: Great, I appreciate your help.